# How to access a webkit based site on android via selenium webdriver

Tags: android, sqlite, selenium, webkit, selenium-webdriver

I am writing an automated test case for a website that uses webkit, specifically sqlite.  When I attempt to do this with Selenium webdriver on an Android device, it just loads a blank screen.

I have set 'databaseEnabled' in desiredCapabilities to True.

I have been able to both access the site from the same Android device's normal web browser, and using webdriver on an iOS based device.

The problem can be seen if you navigate to this page: [Database Test Page](http://zdiles.chaosnet.org/dbTest.html), Which comes from: [mobilehtml5](http://www.mobilehtml5.com/post/401111526/tutorial-your-first-mobile-html5-app-offline-storage)

When you access it from a normal Android browser, you can add scores as expected.  If you try to do the same with the following python code, then no change is made to the page:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

phoneAddress = "http://172.28.0.79:8080/wd/hub"
dbTest = "http://zdiles.chaosnet.org/dbTest.html"

androidDes = webdriver.common.desired_capabilities.DesiredCapabilities.ANDROID
androidDes['databaseEnabled'] = True

driver = webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver(phoneAddress, androidDes)

driver.get(dbTest)

driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("test")
driver.find_element_by_id("upload").click()
```

Comment: do you have any relevant code to share?

Comment: I've added an example of the same problem in a slightly different form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be the result of a bug in android's WebDriver.  For more details on the bug's status see: [Issue 4494](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4494&thanks=4494&ts=1346429477)